# How to update a sub document collection using MongoDB and C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection that contains documents of this form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50f81542a63cfa27fca7df43"),
    "_t" : "ClockRecord",
    "ClockName" : "AAA-TEST123-002",
    "IngestionDateTime" : ISODate("2013-01-17T15:14:10.757Z"),
    "FilesList" : 
    [
        {
            "FileName" : "AAA-TEST123-002.mpg",
            "FileStatus" : "Arriving",
        }, 
        {
            "FileName" : "AAA-TEST123-002.aiff",
            "FileStatus" : "Arriving",
        }
    ]
 }
```

which use these 2 types:

```
public class ClockRecord : IDatabaseRecord
{
    public ClockRecord()
    {
        FilesList = new List<ClockRecordFile>();
    }

    public string ClockName { get; set; }

    public DateTime IngestionDateTime { get; set; }        

    public List<ClockRecordFile> FilesList { get; set; }

    public BsonObjectId _id { get; set; }
}

public class ClockRecordFile
{
     public string FileName { get; set; }

     public string FileStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I have read a lot of Stack replies and mongodb sites and this seems to be the correct technique:

```
var collection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<ClockRecord>("Clocks");
var update = Update.Set("FilesList.FileStatus", "TEST");
var result = collection.Update(
        Query.And(
                   Query.EQ("_id", clockDocumentID),
                   Query.ElemMatch("FilesList",Query.EQ("FileName","AAA-TEST123-002.mpg"))
                 ),  
                 update, UpdateFlags.Upsert
                              );
```

but nothing happens.
How do I update a FileStatus in the sub-document?

My final goal is to replace a FilesList sub document with a different sub-document so if you know how to do that as well that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 7):

Seems there should be a $ in the Update.Set portion of the code.

This works

```
var collection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<ClockRecord>("Clocks");
var update = Update.Set("FilesList.$.FileStatus", "TEST");      <-----$ added here
var result = collection.Update(
        Query.And(
          Query.EQ("_id", clockDocumentID),
          Query.ElemMatch("FilesList",Query.EQ("FileName","AAA-TEST123-002.mpg"))
        ),  
        update, UpdateFlags.Upsert
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with above solution is that it will update only first matching document in the array .Using $ operator you can only update first matching document .Currently mongodb does not provide functionality to update multiple array elements using position operator($) .Have a look at the below link 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Comment: True but my FileName's are unique within a clock document so I can get away with it.  Adding an _id to each sub-document (which I did later) gives you a proper unique key to use in Query.ElemMatch("FilesList", Query.EQ("_id", clockFileRecord._id))